# Only one product available for In App Purchase - why?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Cheers,

I am currently developing my first app featuring In App Purchases. Everything is set up and working (in sandbox mode, app has not yet been submitted), except for one issue:

Of the three products I created, only one will be retrieved by the SKProductsRequest. I double and triple-checked the IDs, everything seems to be fine. The one product which could be retrieved is the first one I created, in case that matters. I was able to purchase it without any problems.

What could be the trouble with the other two?

Thanks!!

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention - i checked the invalidProductIdentifiers array that comes with the response, and it contains the missing products. Seems like something is wrong with the way I set the products up, although I couldn't imagine what that would be. The products are almost identical and the IDs are only slightly different... I'm clueless..

**Edit2:**
After I added a few more products for testing purposes, some (not all) of them where actually available for purchase. Although further testing is necessary, it appears like only those products are available which are cheaper than the original one (or are below some magical limit..). Can you guys make anything out of this?

**Edit3:**
After quite some time and even more testing, still no success. I am pretty sure now that this is connected to the product price. Products below a certain pricing do appear, while those above that price don't. I haven't bothered finding the exact price tier demarking the border, but the scheme is quite obvious anyway. The question that remains is - why?? Why should a price tier that I may freely select be inappropriate for sale? And we're still talking about the sandbox here, so the products didn't even go through review (thus no opportunity to get rejected). I'm puzzled. Any help greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Issue resolved. See update to my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok although I didn't find a solution, at least now I **do** know what's going on.

I took the time to pin down the first price tier that would make a product unavailable, which turned out to be tier 80. After that I did a little more research and found out that this seems to be a known bug - although tiers 80 and onward can be selected in the product setup, those products will never appear in the store.

Unfortunately I still don't know whether this is intended behaviour (and the tiers shouldn't be selectable in the first place), or if those tiers should be available but noone fixed the bug because there was no demand for in-app-purchases beyond 499$.

I'll file a bug report and keep you posted.

**Update:**

My bugreport has been processed today. All price tiers are now available and products with tier 80 and above are actually available for purchase. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ensure that all 3 are marked as cleared for sale, and that Apple has reviewed and approved them in iTunesConnect.</strike>

If you don't want to post the actual identifiers here, can you ensure that they have no special characters or spaces? Is there anything common about the failing identifiers in terms of the identifier structure?

Sometimes it takes some time to propagate through the servers. I have seen it take up to 1 day. Have the identifiers been in the system for awhile now?

Comment: All of the products are cleared for sale. I have not sent them into review yet, since I'm still doing testing in the sandbox.

Comment: Identifiers are completely "harmless" and differ only by one numerical character. I just added two bogus products (Identifiers: "hgjj" and "test") and one of them, test, has actually been retrieved, while hgjj was still missing. Then I noticed that they differ in pricing - so I added two more products, named "expensive" and "cheap", with price tiers above and below the original products price. And guess what - cheap appears, expensive does not... I still have to verify that, but it appears like products more expensive than the original one cannot be retrieved...

Comment: Well, the first products were created a couple of hours ago. But the bogus products I just created for testing were available only seconds later, while the "old" products are still missing. Deleting and creating them again didn't help. It might be worth noting that all of the original products are quite expensive - ranging from 200$ to 999$. Maybe there's a limit? The documentation doesn't mention one, though.

Comment: I would still wait a day or so to see if it propagates. You can't assume that just because one went through all should go through. I seem to remember a limit to being $999

Comment: Well, it's been a few days now and nothing changed. The same products that were available on friday are still available now. Concerning the limit - 999$ is the most expensive tier which can be selected, thus representing the price limit. I selected various tiers for my products and only those appeared for which I selected a tier below the first product ones. That's still the only pattern I noticed in this context, although I don't understand it at all.